# Powershell test-path issue: Checking if folder exists on server

Tags: powershell, directory, remote-server

I have a powershell script (test.ps1) residing on ServerA. All the script is supposed to do is check whether a folder exists on the server. I am executing the script from a client (within same network)

test.ps1

```
test-path E:\automation
# returns whether this folder exists on ServerA
```

I am calling that script from ComputerB's powershell.

```
PS > pushd \\serverA\scripts
PS > .\test.ps1
```

Output:

```
False
```

Expected Output:

```
True
```

Problem:

```
The script is trying to locate the folder on the "local system" (ComputerB) rather than ServerA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried powershell remoting:

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ServerA

This will allow powershell commands to be run on ServerA

Comment: I thought that pushd would do that. Thanks. Will try.

Comment: Pushd remembers the path that you have moved to.

Comment: So we run the Enter-PSSession command on Computer B, correct?

Comment: Correct. You need to enable psremoting on ServerA

Comment: @Chriseyre2000, `pushd` remembers the path you moved *from*. So you could `popd` to initial location later. But generally, yes, it is `cd` with some additional functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`invoke-command \\serverA\scripts\test.ps1 -computername serverB`

Comment: How can I pass arguments to this script (test.ps1)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with PSSession. My working code:

```powershell
$ip = "<server ip / dns name>"
$user = "<your user name>"
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ip -Credential $user

$serverTestFolder = "c:\"

if (Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {Test-Path -path $args[0]} -ArgumentList $serverTestFolder) {
    # here you are when folder exist on remote server
}
```

Important here is that you need to pass variable `$serverTestFolder` as argument via `ArgumentList` and then consume it via `$args` ([0] is position of argument within ArgumentList).

Answer (score -2):

```
Test-Path "filesystem::\\\Srv\share"
```

Comment: What if it is not shared?

Comment: please add a description as to how this resolves the problem. [answer]